# Where can I find documentation for Barnes and Noble search API?

Tags: api

Couldn't find one but can't believe they don't have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do not have one.

http://www.barnesandnoble.com/help/help.asp

Answer (score 16):

They actually do have one, but unlike Amazon, it's private, and getting access is a very manual and time consuming process.

Here's the process I went through:

1. Sign up as an affiliate @ http://affiliates.barnesandnoble.com/join-now/ (http://affiliates.barnesandnoble.com/ has more information). You don't actually sign up with B&N, you sign up with LinkShare.
2. Email Ahelp@book.com with your LinkShare ID and the URL of the site you are building
3. Answer any questions they have about your site
4. Get approved as an affiliate
5. Accept the affiliate invitation on LinkShare
6. Email the LinkShare contact requesting API access
7. Wait for them to forward that email and B&N to get you set up (took a week in my case)
8. Receive an email with your access key, and a few 3 page word docs of documentation

After that, you're set.

Comment: I wonder if you can share the docs with me. I need to see if their search API supports a specific operation. If not then there is no point to sign up.

Comment: Sadly they deny access for educational/academic purposes. Business only.

Answer (score 0):

Even better, they claim to have one, but when you register, there's actually nothing there:

http://developer.bn.com/page